# Is there a free places auto complete api or library

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-places-api, google-places

I have been trying to build a weather application for Android while building the application I wanted to add an option to select a city by name and not only by coordinates.
I wanted to add an auto-complete section that allows the user to enter a city name and he gets all the options for cities with that name, that will, later on, convert to the city coordinates.

I found google places API but it costs money.
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete.

I was wondering if anyone knows a free API or a library for Android that autocompletes cities names and their coordinates, Or if it is possible to retrieve cities names from google without API key

Comment: Have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54066098/8274756)