# How to get a list of addresses by a search without the map?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm trying to get a list of addresses by searching an address in an `editText`, using Google Maps API.

For example, if I'm searching for an address in the editText at the top of the screen, below it, there will be a list of addresses that you can choose.

I don't need the map part of it, just the results, and the search box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the option of using the `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` - when I first added it, I had no billing account so you should be good:

1. Add it on the XML

   ```
   <fragment
   android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"
   />
   ```
2. Use `PlaceSelectionListener`:

   ```
   PlaceAutocompleteFragment autocompleteFragment = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)
   getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.place_autocomplete_fragment);

   autocompleteFragment.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
   @Override
   public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
       // TODO: Get info about the selected place.
       Log.i(TAG, "Place: " + place.getName());
   }

   @Override
   public void onError(Status status) {
       // TODO: Handle the error.
       Log.i(TAG, "An error occurred: " + status);
   }
   });
   ```

   **Note from the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete)**:

   > The Google Places API requires API level 12 or higher for the support of `PlaceAutocompleteFragment` objects. If you are targeting an application earlier than API level 12, you can access the same functionality through the `SupportPlaceAutocompleteFragment` class. You must also include the Android v4 Support Library.

Comment: Thanks, I've already figured it out antoher way but this way worked for me too!

Comment: Can you tell me how you did it ? Gaining knowledge is always good.

Comment: Yeah, I followed this youtube video to acheive it :https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Trdd9EnmqY&index=8&list=PLgCYzUzKIBE-vInwQhGSdnbyJ62nixHCt .

Answer (score 0):

First you need a component, something like [AutoCompleteTextView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView).

Second Google has a documentations about autosuggestion address. It is so simple, register, create an api key and so on. [Here is a link to doc.](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete)

Logic: User press type a text, component fired a callback `onTextChanged` and you make a request to get suggestion list, after show a received list to user.

Comment: It says I got to create a billing account though... Is there any way of avoiding that?

Comment: Have a look at my answer below , maybe it can help you.